# How to install Laravel v5.2.15 when I have already installed v5.6.12?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to install a lower version of laravel when I have already installed a higher version in my htdocs. But it throws an error.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6>composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.2.15 s6
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.15)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.15): Loading from cache
Created project in s6
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\artisan:0
PHP   2. require() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\artisan:16
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\artisan:0
PHP   2. require() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\artisan:16

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0007     344912   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\artisan:0
    0.0016     346488   2. require('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap\autoload.php') C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\artisan:16


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0007     344912   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\artisan:0
    0.0016     346488   2. require('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\bootstrap\autoload.php') C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-6\s6\artisan:16

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

But when I tried installing laravel v5.6.12, it gets installed easily again. Please tell me a way around to install a lower version of laravel while keeping the higher version. Thanks.

#### Errors:Updates suggested by a member

I was suggested to download laravel's particular version manually and I did also tried to update composer but still facing problem. The error that has occurred is shown below:

[image: error]

Comment: you cannot keep both in same project, you have to create 2 different project

Comment: I have created 2 different folder in `htdocs` and they are kept separately.

Comment: remove both folder and run `composer clear-cache` and run create project command again

Comment: Can't do that. Have a web project in `5.6.12`, have removed `5.2.15` several times as wasn't correctly installed but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried with after you cleared cache ? `composer clear-cache`

Comment: Yes, tried it too. Cleared the cache and installed it again, also installed `composer dump-autoload` separately but still it is throwing an error to install `bootstrap/app.php`

Comment: then try this: go to https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases/tag/v5.2.15 and download the laravel manually and run a composer update

Comment: Thanks, will try that but isn't it going to be a problem if I manually download laravel? And why do we need to update composer afterwards?

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth still a problem, updated the question plz see the error.

Comment: did you run `composer update` or `composer install` ?

Comment: Composer update

Comment: You sure it installed the all the dependency ? Check vendor folder

Comment: What should I check in `vendor` folder?

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth It is done, ran a different command, `composer update --no-scripts` and it works now.But somehow, after updating, the framework that got installed is `v5.2.45`

Comment: No problem gl 

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this command to install a clean copy of laravel 5.2.15?

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravelProjectFolder "5.2.15"
```

Comment: Several times but it throws the above mentioned error.